# Create razor view without web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

We're currently using a product to send emails, and are doing so from a number of executables that run periodically.  This product has very limited processing of dynamic data, so if we want a table from a list, we have to create the table in our C# code and send the HTML as a single variable, which causes us to have HTML in our config file.

A coworker saw [this type of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) and thought we might be able to use it.  So I'm trying to develop a proof-of-concept of creating a view in an executables and converting it to a string (we would then develop our emails outside of the emailing product and send the whole thing in as a single string.

My questions are:

1) **Is there a better way of doing this?**  Bringing in the MVC framework certainly isn't what it's intended for.  If there's another product out there that will do what we want (allow us to easily create a dynamic email) that is easy to use and more suited, that would be great.

2) **Should I just fake out all the data?**  If I create fake http context and all that jazz, I can get it to do what I want.

3) **Is there an easier way to convert a view to a string, based on a ViewModel?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need HTTP to be involved at all, you can simply run Razor engine from C# directly using `RazorEngine` project - there is a great project that allows you to do so - https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine.

It allows you to use Razor as general purpose templating engine (rather than something MVC-specific).

Simple example from GitHub:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Alternatively, if you still want that to be accessible via HTTP, you could do this relatively easy with `ASP.NET Web API`, in  a very lightweight manner - without having to worry about ASP.NET whatsoever (since you can even self host that).

`WebApiContrib` has a Razor view formatter already available - https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.RazorViewEngine